# Keeping the data in a service and displaying it on a view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to clean up my controller and move all the data fetching logic to the service, so that there wouldn't be the following code in my controller:

```
myService.fetchData().then(funtion(response) {
    self.data = response.data;
});
```

This is my achievement so far: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nfe03kq2NRYuoh72aTtC)

Is this a good practice? What problems could rise from this?

Also how can I remove the `app.users()` call in my template and leave only `app.users` like a variable?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to move the logic to the service, but you should assign the users to a property (model) instead of relinking to the service from the controller:

```
var self = this;

this.fetchUsers = function() {
    // assign result to 'users' property, which can be used
    // in the view
    UserService.fetchUsers().then(function(data){
        // success
        self.users = data;
        // or, because you remember the users in your service:
        // self.users = UserService.getUsers();
    });
}
```

and your view:

```
<button ng-click="app.fetchUsers()">Get users</button>
<github-table columns="app.columns" rows="app.users"></github-table>
```

**EDIT**

the service:

```
function fetchUsers () {
    // return the $http call (which is a promise) so the 
    // .then can be used
    return $http
        .get('https://api.github.com/users')
        .success(function (response) {
            users = response;
        });
}
```

Comment: And my UserService.fetchUsers() method should return a promise? Maybe you can include how should it look like? Thanks.

Comment: So I guess there are no way to avoid  UserService.fetchUsers().then(function(data){
        self.users = data;
}); in my controller and use only self.users = UserService.fetchUsers()?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should be in the controller logic because it increases extensibility.

For an example you might call this service method in two different controllers and wants to handle the response differently. And also if you have a function that needs to execute after all the data has been retrieved, then this logic is the best.

```
myService.fetchData().then(funtion(response) {
    self.data = response.data;
});
```